# Lua - How to remove quotes around integers in strings

Tags: string, lua

So I have this string:

```
{"scores":{"1":["John",60],"2":["Jude",60],"3":["Max",60],"4":["Kyle",60],"5":["Smith",60],"6":["Mark",50],"7":["Luke",40],"8":["Anne",30],"9":["Bruce",20],"10":["kazuo",10]}}
```

There are a number of integers there that have quotes around them, and I want to get rid of them. How do I do that? I already tried out:

```
print(string.gsub(string, '/"(\d)"/', "%1"));
```

but it does not work. :(

Comment: This JSON is a little odd; I would have expected to see `{"scores":[["John",60],["Jude",60],["Max",60],["Kyle",60],["Smith",60],["Mark",50],["Luke",40],["Anne",30],["Bruce",20],["kazuo",10]]}` instead.

Comment: @Neil: I was supposed to use that so I tried validating it via: http://jsonlint.com/ first. It was invalid so I didn't use it.

Comment: I don't know whether it was how I copied it but there were some invalid characters. `{"scores":[["John",60],["Jude",60],["Max",60],["Kyle",60],["Smith",60],["Mark",50],["Luke",40],["Anne",30],["Bruce",20],["kazuo",10]]}` validates OK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lua does not have *regular expressions* like Perl, instead, it does have [*patterns*](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#6.4.1). These are similar with a few differences.

There is no need for delimiting slashes `/ /`, and the escaping character is `%` but not `\`. Otherwise, your trial is essentially correct:

```
print(string.gsub(str, '"(%d+)"', "%1"))
```

Where `str` is the variable containing the input string. Also note that [`string.gsub`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-string.gsub) returns **2** values, which are both printed, the second result being the number of substitutions. Use an extra pair of parentheses to keep only the first result.

You can simplify a little the notation using the colon `:` operator :

```
print((str:gsub('"(%d+)"', "%1")))
```

Comment: Awesome! thank you so much! I've only started using Lua so I'm still not very well-versed. Thank you, this worked perfectly!